# Use Wii U as a network bridge?

Tags: home-networking, network-adapter, bridge, wii-u

I've recently moved my entertainment system far away from where my modem/router and wired Ethernet. The only device I have in the system with a wifi antenna is my Wii U. I also have a USB-to-Ethernet adapter that I've formerly used to give the Wii U a wired connection to my network. There are other devices in my entertainment system that I'd like to give network access which don't have wireless interfaces:

- Xbox 360
- Samsung smart TV

Can I use the Wii U as wireless-to-wired bridge for any of these devices?

### Other details:

Eventually, I may cave and buy a wifi adapter, but for now I'm seeing if I can make do with what's in the house. (I'm moving abroad soon, so I'm not up for acquiring much.) I own two extra routers, but none of my routers support a "client mode," and only one of my three routers support WDS. I feel like I've exhausted these options.

Comment: The Wii U is not capable of being a network bridge, being a network bridge, requires software support.  You should just get yourself a cheap router that supports DD-WRT or OpenWRT and configure it to be a network bridge.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to move on with my life. Feel free to post your comment as an answer. In the meantime, I have a big ugly CAT5 cable running through my living room.